# Processing mdx cube in pentaho

Tags: mdx, pentaho, olap, olap-cube, pentaho-cde

I'm using pentaho BI server(biserver-ce-5.0.1-stable) version.

once i create the data source for reporting and analyse purpose(OLAP cube) it's working fine using at that time Data but i need to know how to process it according to time period(need to change the cube data after mid night).

please share the ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Pentaho Data Integration from [here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/5.0.1-stable/)

Go step by step when you created data source and write it down.
Then make Job (or Transformation if it's simple) and make a scheduler.

[Here](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpdi_user_guide%2Ftopic_starting_pdi.html) you will find info about PDI.

Good luck!